# Sheets of fresh pasta sticking together

Tags: pasta

I make fresh pasta regularly and it usually works out well. There is one exception. If I make sheets of pasta for lasagna or cannelloni they tend to stick together during cooking so that I have difficulty separating them from each other and themselves. Does anyone have a suggestion? I have heard that adding oil to the water may help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You may just be cooking too much at once.  When I make lasagna or rolled pasta, like cannelloni, I cook 2 to 3 sheets at a time, building my lasagna (or filling the pasta) as I go.  I remove the cooked sheets to a clean kitchen towel.  Proceed with the construction when they are just cool enough to handle, then add more fresh pasta to the cooking pot.

Comment: Anytime I boil stuff like this lasagna pasta or bagels, I get out the roasting pan and heat it over two flames as if I'm reducing gravy. Gives me great surface area for maximum efficiency

Answer (score 1):

maybe they stick because they are overcooked...however, when boiling any type of pasta you should always add a spoonful or so of vegetable oil to help them separate.

I never pre-cook lasagna sheets...fresh pasta cooks so quickly that it will be thoroughly cooked while in the oven, even if every sauce is pre-cooked...and even store-bought dry lasagna sheets or cannelloni tubes will be entirely cooked if they are covered with sauces and the dish is cooked for 20 or more minutes.

Comment: I made cannelloni this past weekend and took your advice. I made the fresh pasta, but didn't cook it before making the individual cannellonies. It was brilliant. You were right! I baked everything in the oven and it turned out perfectly. Thank you so much. I will try lasagna next. Tom